# android eclipse Switch Case not working

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have an app that alot of users have helped me on so far and I really appreciate it. Now I have a force close issue when the case is exicuted below. When I click the button 2 it will load the Ship.Class and everything works like I want it too. When I click button1 It will not load Ocean.Class and it force closes. The Ocean.Class is a mirror of the Ship.Class except for the variable names have been updated to reflect the different class. Is using the variable (a) like I am in the switch not something that is allowable?

```
package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Ocean extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button1;
public Spinner spinner1;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ocean);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,  
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            playSound(R.raw.ocean_birds);
            break;
    }
}

// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};
 }
```

This is what I gathered from the Logcat

```
09-17 11:11:15.704: I/dalvikvm(1634):   | sysTid=1634 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-    error:2] handle=-1207757760
09-17 11:11:58.690: E/Trace(1665): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-17 11:18:47.446: I/dalvikvm(1735):   | sysTid=1735 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1207757760
09-17 11:39:46.139: E/Trace(1758): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-17 11:39:53.705: I/dalvikvm(1758):   | sysTid=1758 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1207757760
09-17 11:40:00.356: E/Trace(1774): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)     


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Ship" />

    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Ocean" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is there any stack trace or log output available?

Comment: "Is using the variable (a) like I am in the switch not something that is allowable?"...Perfectly allowable. The problem is most likely in `Ocean.java`. We will let you know after seeing the logcat

Comment: Did you add Ocean-activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: The logcat is that thing at the bottom of eclipse where a lot of red messages appear when the app crashes

Comment: 09-17 11:18:47.456: A/libc(1735): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1735 (pmachine.gamble)                        09-17 11:40:00.356: E/Trace(1774): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
This is what is in red. I also did add the activity to the manafest

Comment: in the bar on top of the logcat view, there is a dropdown menu, select "error", it will show only error type messages, then select all messages and copy-paste them in the question, please

Comment: ok thanks, could you also post the code for Ocean class?

Comment: Please provide the code for Ocean.class because there's a problem with that particular activity.

Comment: That's weird, the error message in the logcat doesn't say anything about class, I would try to understand why you're having that error first

Comment: I dont suppose you see anything wrong with the Ocean Class?

Comment: exactly, the error showed in the logcat says it cannot find trace file, if we had the stack trace we could see where the app is actually crashing. I would try to solve this problem first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code works perfectly fine. I did try to run it even on the emulator and it's working perfectly fine:

public class Ocean extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button1;
public Spinner spinner1;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ocean);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn1:
        playSound(R.raw.test);
        /*
         * getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
         */break;
    }
}

// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};
```

}

The music keeps playing even when the app is closed.
I don't think there's anything wrong with the code.

Comment: In my layout I just spinner and a button. The ID's are same as yours and also in the manifest I just did this:
<activity
            android:name="com.mike.webview.Ocean"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: 09-17 22:19:00.411: E/Trace(1690): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
This is shown in the logcat. I dont know what this error is or how to fix it. It is what happens when I try to load my Ocean.java and the force close happens

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have added Ocean class (activity) in android manifest file .
2. Check whether you have id same as *button1* in the layout .

Comment: i checked the id and it is the same. i will post the manifest, it could very well be I did that wrong.

Comment: Firstly you are not describing your question properly , then down-voting the answers ! how mean !

Comment: I havnt down voted anything, I asked the original question and have added more of the code as other users requested. the problem is still the same that I originally asked, it keeps force closing.